# Angular 12 auto api cache

Tags: angular, angular12

I just upgraded Angular version from 10 to 12 and I noticed when page A loads for the first time and then somehow by a link I come back to page A no API is shown in network tab. I placed `console.log('test')` and traced the issue and found out HTTP request is being called and response is being returned but somehow Angular 12 is automatically caching the request and not calling the API again.
I want to disable this feature but i cant find what to do.

Reproduce:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getDashboardInfo().subscribe(
    result => {console.log(result)},
    error => {console.log(error)}
  );
}
```

and `this.service.getDashboardinfo()` is:

```
return this.http.get(this.api.DASHBOARD, { observe: 'response', headers: headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) });
```

For the second visit of this page `console.log(result)` is being called but in network tab XHR nothing is being shown and Api response is being returned instant instead of taking the normal 500ms and i assume this is something to do with Angular 12 automatically caching my request.

This is only happening with `ng serve` and in build or SSR version everything works fine.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VimalPatel I tried to add a reproduce, I'm pretty sure there should be a flag or a setting for this because it is happening to all of my HTTP requests and has nothing to do with my code.

Comment: There is no such settings in angular 12. Unless you have configured  caching in service worker.

Comment: @VimalPatel I'm not using service worker,  I'm just calling a simple GET HTTP request which is being called everytime i visit any of my pages in angular 10 but in angular 12 each page is calling API once and second time it loads instantly.

Comment: Its difficult to tell without looking into complete code.

Comment: Probability 1: ngOnit is not happening, may somehow your not destroying the component and recreating. Probability 2: your service not actually making the api call second time many it is return the observable of previously recived response. It can be a bug in redux implementation. Probability 3: you have an interceptor caching api responses.

Comment: @GirishSadanandan ngOninit is happening, HttpClient.get.. is being called so API should be called, in interceptor only next.handle(request) is being called for this api.

Comment: if you are not sure interceptor is being called or not place a new interceptor as first one and see what you get there. All check for all interceptors and validate what it does, simple things like next.handle(request) after an if condition without an else block can destroy the flow. Probably something might there

Comment: @GirishSadanandan I tried something today , i added a random query param to the end of my API urls and now that the url is changing each time API is being called everytime, I'm 100% sure this is some kind of cache but i just upgraded from angular 10 to 12 and i didn't add anything it must be some feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went through the entire APP and found the problem: TransferHttpCacheModule . removing that it solves the issue. I was supposed to add the BrowserTransferStateModule for SSR however I added that by mistake instead

Comment: How and where do I remove it from? I am stuck on this issue since two weeks. Pls help

Comment: @Rahul Find TransferHttpCacheModule in your project, If you find any there is a good chance that you wanted to import BrowserTransferStateModule for SSR and you imported that by mistake.
After removing those imports you can replace them with importing BrowserTransferStateModule.